# Append string to member when encoding a type to JSON

Tags: json, go

I have this type with a value member called "Url".  When encoding this type to json, I want to prepend the HOST value in front of the Url.  What is the best way to achieve that?

In this example, the `Println` statement prints `{"url":"/thisurl"}`, I want it to print `{"url":"http://myhost.com/thisurl"}`

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/json"

type Post struct {
  Url string `json:"url"`
}

const (
  HOST = "http://myhost.com"
)

func main() {
  post := Post{"/thisurl"}
  marshaled, _ := json.Marshal(post)

  fmt.Println(string(marshaled))
   //{"url":"/thisurl"}
}
```

## Update

I could re-assign post.Url right before the `json.Marshal` line

```
post.Url = fmt.Sprintf("%s%s", HOST, post.Url)
```

But that feels a little messy, if I have to remember to do a reassignment every time I want to encode to json.

I don't want to change the value of `post.Url`, I simply want to change how it is represented as json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the (un)marshalling behaviour then use a custom type that implements [`json.Marshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) (and possibly `json.Unmarshaler`).

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Post struct {
    URL URLString `json:"url"`
}

const (
    Host = "http://myhost.com"
)

type URLString string

func (u URLString) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(fmt.Sprintf(`"%s%s"`, Host, u)), nil
}

func main() {
    post := Post{"/thisurl"}
    marshaled, _ := json.Marshal(post)

    fmt.Println(string(marshaled))
    //{"url":"http://myhost.com/thisurl"}
}
```

[<kbd>Playground</kbd>](https://play.golang.org/p/e-a7LNABpI)

(also note, using all caps for constants is [not idiomatic](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#mixed-caps), and `golint` recommends `URL`, `MyURL`, `HTTP`, `ID` vs `Url`, `MyUrl`, or `Id`).

Comment: BTW, one minor drawback of this approach is you may need to do things like `post.URL = urlstring(strVar)` (so you should probably export that type if the fields is exported) if you directly assign from a non-constant. If that bothers you, you could possibly move the `MarshalJSON` method up to the `Post` type but then you have to handle marshalling of the entire type yourself :(.